# WCF Services with Appfabric Service Bus endpoints

Tags: wcf, service, appfabric, bus

Is it possible to host WCF Services with Appfabric Service Bus endpoints in IIS6 on Windows Server 2003 64 bit?

If not, are there any alternatives apart from upgrading the OS or using a Windows Service?

Any help would be great

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any way to accomplish this with "pure" IIS6 as it lacks WAS and the auto-start feature that is needed to hook the IIS application up to the ServiceBus address before that application has actually been "spun up" by some outside client.

That said if you had some kind of start-up task on the server that would make a request to the application so that it could register with the Service Bus inside of the traditional Application OnStart lifecycle event, that could be a possible solution.